# Is there the equivalent of a WPF GridSplitter in Uno Platform?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp-xaml, uno-platform

I am just learning Uno Platform and creating one of my apps in XAML. I'm used to WPF which has a Grid and GridSplitter which lets the user resize columns or rows. Is there the equivalent of this in Uno?

I've looked through their controls and it seems like a lot of the controls follow the Windows UI controls, but I can't find anything similar to a GridSplitter that lets me resize columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the GridSplitter is not part of Uno platform itself but rather WindowsCommunityToolkit which has been ported to Uno.

https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.WindowsCommunityToolkit

Specifically:

https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/uno/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/GridSplitter/GridSplitter.cs

Docs:

- Uno: https://platform.uno/docs/articles/uno-community-toolkit.html
- Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/gridsplitter

Nuget:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Uno.Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls

Code:

```
<Page
...
  xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
...
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <controls:GridSplitter Grid.Column="1">
           
        </controls:GridSplitter>
...
```